# JQuery index() - Which way around?

Tags: javascript, jquery, collections, this, indexof

In the following piece of code:

```
$('body').on('click', onClickSelector, function(e) {

  console.log($(this).index(onClickSelector));
  console.log($(onClickSelector).index(this));

}
```

Both logs seem to give the correct index value. That is, the index of `this`, within the `onClickSelector` collection.

But which is technically the correct way to get that value? Or are the two interchangeable? Also, are there any issues that could arise from using one over the other?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> But which is technically the correct way to get that value?

They're interchangeable in that instance (since you don't already have the set of matches handy). If you look at the jQuery code under the covers, which looks like this:

```
index: function( elem ) {

    // No argument, return index in parent
    if ( !elem ) {
        return ( this[ 0 ] && this[ 0 ].parentNode ) ? this.first().prevAll().length : -1;
    }

    // Index in selector
    if ( typeof elem === "string" ) {
        return indexOf.call( jQuery( elem ), this[ 0 ] );
    }

    // Locate the position of the desired element
    return indexOf.call( this,

        // If it receives a jQuery object, the first element is used
        elem.jquery ? elem[ 0 ] : elem
    );
},
```

...they end up being the same thing: A call to the internal `indexOf` passing in a set and an element to find.